# List in scala not getting updated

Tags: scala, list, tuples, foldleft

I am new to Scala Collections and currently I want to separate a given list of strings into a tuple of two lists `(List[String], List[String])`, which contains list of palindrome strings and rest of the of the input strings.

For example, 
if input is `List("racecar", "abcd", "lilil", "effg")`
output should be `(List("racecar", "lilil"), List("abcd", "effg"))`

I have got a solution using filter. But, currently, trying to refine my solution using foldLeft. My new approach is as follows:

```
def stringTuples2(strings: List[String]): (List[String], List[String]) = {
strings.foldLeft((List[String](), List[String]()))((b, a) => {
  if (a.equals(a.reverse)) { b._1 :+ a; b }
  else { b._2 :+ a; b }
})}
```

I am not sure, what I am doing wrong, but the output for this solution is Tuple of two empty lists, i.e. (List(), List()).

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a perfect use case for `partition`: `myList.partition(x => x.reverse == x)`

Comment: Thanks @Akavall for valuable input!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your attempt to modify `b` creates a new `List`, you then throw the new `List` away and return `b`, which is unchanged. Take out the `;b` part and return the updated tuple: `(b._1 :+ a, b._2)` or `(b._1, b._2 :+ a)`

BTW, here's a different approach to the solution.

```
List("racecar", "abcd", "lilil", "effg").partition(s => s == s.reverse)
```

Comment: Thanks, @jwvh ! Your explanation really helped me to understand the problem. Also, I understand that `partition()` will really make my life easier in such use cases, it's just that I am trying to learn the different functions and their (possible) caveats.

Thanks again!

Comment: The best way to thank someone on stack overflow is to accept their answer if it's the best response you have got, and it solves your question.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach , got it! I realize, it's a good learning of Stack Overflow protocols, in addition to Scala! :)